# Trying to use [] to get value of parameter

Tags: php, parameters

I'm trying to get the value of some URL parameters in PHP and can't seem to get `[]` to detect this in the URL.

This works:

```
  <?php if ($params['sms_banner'] === 'true') { ?><div id="sms-banner-legacy"> SMS Banner </div><?php } ?>
```

This doesn't work:

```
  <?php if ($params['payday[sms_banner]'] === 'true') { ?><div id="sms-banner-legacy"> Legacy SMS Banner </div><?php } ?>
```

When I go to `http://someurl.com/page?payday[sms_banner]=true` it should then show the `<div>` on the page, but instead it can't pick up the value.

Comment: Can you post the whole code in your question, and you can try with $param['payday']['sms_banner']

Comment: This is the whole code.

Comment: `$params['payday[sms_banner]']` doesn't make any sense

Comment: You must define `$params` somewhere - this is hardly the entire code ;-)

Comment: What is `$params` defined as? How are you using it? As Zain just beat me to, `$params['payday[sms_banner]']` doesn't seem quite right.

Comment: This is a Cake PHP 2 application, `$params` is defined as: `$params = $this->request->query;`

Comment: Then `var_dump($params);` and see what it contains.

Answer (score 2):

As you are passing array in url, you can get the value of same using

```
$_GET['payday']['sms_banner']
```

Comment: This works: `($params['payday']['sms_banner'] === 'true')`

Answer (score 0):

php translates that syntax to an array key value, try `$_GET['payday']['sms_banner']` or `params['payday']['sms_banner']` in your case.